# Multivariate Linear Regression

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, linear

**Question:**
Please help me to explain what the output of the generalized linear model (glm) means.  I understand the inputs, but I don't understand what the outputs of the fit are, or what the they mean in terms of the relationship between satisfaction and infidelity.  Do the results that I am getting mean that I have not performed the analysis correctly?  I am pretty new to both the topic and tools.

**Background:**
So, I am trying to compute a multivariate linear regression model in order to examine the extent to which sexual satisfaction is associated with infidelity. Infidelity has 3 separate measures to actually test infidelity with 2 separate time points (measured 2 weeks apart)

The issue I am having is how to interpret the output and put this into a table. So I decided to take the average of each infidelity measure at time 1 and 2, and sexual satisfaction at time 1 and 2. Then I run the analysis by going through General Linear Model, Multivariate, placed my 3 infidelity variables in the DV box and satisfaction in the fixed factors with a covariate. So now I have the output but I don't know how to interpret it. I believe I would need to report the b, β, Confidence Intervals and P value. Although I cant seem to find the β value which leads me to believe I have run the test wrong.

This is how I run the test: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21476743

I hope this is a better explanation.

Comment: I think you need to expand your description of your data-set and tell us what your scientific question is for anyone to be helpful.

Comment: Ok, no problem, I will edit my question

Comment: This remains unintelligible to me (what is "going through General Linear Model, Multivariate"?, eg). & it relies on an external link (questions here can have links, but need to be self-contained).

Comment: Sorry if I am not being clear, so on SPSS, I selected General Linear Models, then Multivariate then placed my 3 infidelity variables in the DV box and satisfaction in the fixed factors box and I also included a covariate. My main problem here is trying to report the output with no Beta value. I was reading a paper that conducted the same analysis in which they reported the b, β, CI and significance.

Comment: Please try to identify specific questions (I can see one in there, but clearly that's not everything you need); open ended vague questions where we have to guess what things you don't know aren't really suitable for our format; you may need to do some [search and research](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to more clearly figure out what you want to know.

Comment: You need to be careful about terminology here as what SPSS calls beta (the standardised regession coefficient) is not what most people who do not use SPSS call beta (the population value of the regression coefficient, unstandardised). Perhaps another edit is called for to further clairfy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing as:

- 'condense this into three variables so that I can look at the time points together' and
- 'combined the two variables with two time points into one variable with one time point',

could be a perfectly good analysis, called the 'between estimator'. This entails taking the average over the two time points for each individual, for both the dependent and the independent variables. You then just estimate these combined variables in a normal linear regression model. Note two things however:

- You only model the variation 'between' individuals, i.e. how their independent variables react to the dependent variable, only based on how they differ. Variation over time is not taken into account.
- For correct inference the between estimator assumes that the individual-specific constant (the unobserved characteristic of each individual) is uncorrelated with the regressors (consult the theory on random and fixed effects and their assumptions).

If you are also or additionally interested in effects over time, consider fixed or random effects models.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This makes a lot of sense. So If I am interested in effects over time, how would you do a fixed or random effects model? Sorry I'm quite new to SPSS.

Comment: You are welcome! It would probably be best if you study a bit more on these topics to understand the different models. Then you can decide whether a within or a between estimator or something else is suitable for your specific study.